# c++ calling method from subclass in superclass

Tags: inheritance, methods, subclass

Im a bit new to c++ object programming and need a little bit of help.

Let's say I have class Animal, and subclass cat.
In main programm I made an array of pointers to Animal, like this:

```
Animal* array[10];
array[0] = new Cat();
```

Subclass cat has his own integer, and method getType to return that integer. I'd like to know how do I call this method.

I tried:

```
array[0]->getType()
```

But it says, that method could not be resolved, and that class Animal has no member named getType.
I also tried to make this method virtual and still didn't work.
Any sollutions?

Sincerely

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need a `Cat *` in order to call `getType()`. In C++, pointers are converted (casted) using [casting operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/).

---

If you are certain (this can bite you back in larger programs) that your `array[0]` is really pointing to an object of class `Cat`, you can use (see [ideone](https://ideone.com/9Y8eeT) for complete program)

```cpp
Cat * catPtr = static_cast<Cat *>(array[0]);
catPtr->getType();
```

or, concisely,

```cpp
static_cast<Cat *>(array[0])->getType();
```

Note that this will fail miserably if `array[0]` is not pointer to `Cat`.

---

As long as your classes are polymorphic (contain virtual members), which, in your case (array of base class pointers and running derived methods) should probably be the case, you can use `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast`. It incurs runtime overhead, but will check if the conversion is valid and return `nullptr` if it is not.

Comment: @timcheee Note that while this works, writing code in this way is a bad practice (that's why my answer has been downvoted). Try approaches in other people answers.

Comment: Before I do that sentence, I'm checking in IF statement if the array[i] is pointer to Cat, so I'm certain that I'm not converting other subclasses to Cat

Comment: It is still bad programming practice. If you now it's a `Cat`, it should be a `Cat *` in the first place. If you want an array of various `Animal` subclass objects, you should work with virtual methods instead. See my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare it virtual in the base class, example:

```
virtual void getType() { cout << "Animal" << '\n'; }
```

And in the derived class you can override it:

```
void getType() override { cout << "Cat" << '\n'; }
```

Now you can call `array[0]->getType()` and it will use the overridden `Cat::getType()`

Comment: This is actually better answer than mine. Adding `getType()` bodies would be nice though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you want to have several subclasses of `Animal` which will have the same methods and that you will use array of `Animal *` to call subclasses' methods. If this is the case, then you should make `Animal` class methods `virtual`:

1. Declare all the methods (which you want all your subclasses to have) in `Animal` class
2. If they have a "default" implementation, put that in `Animal`
3. Otherwise, make them purely virtual in `Animal` (see example)
4. In subclasses, override purely virtual methods plus those which will have non-default implementation

So your `Animal` class should look like:

```cpp
class Animal {
    public:
        virtual int getType() = 0; // purely virtual function
};
```

and your `Cat` class should override the methods (*note that the `override` identifier is not necessary, although recommended*)

```cpp
class Cat : public Animal {
    public:
        int getType() override {
            return 42;
        }
};
```

This allows having

```cpp
Animal * array[10];
array[0] = new Cat();
std::cout << array[0]->getType() << std::endl;
```

which will print 42. See [ideone example](http://ideone.com/tzb24p).

Answer (score -1):

If i recall correctly you need to cast the array[0] as a Cat type. So it would be like this

```
dynamic_cast<Cat>(array[0])->getType();
```

This is my first post and i have not tried my suggestion so i apologize in case this is wrong.